# Is there a way to highlight unsaved or changed line in IntelliJ gutter - change tracking

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

Is there a way to highlight unsaved or changed line in IntelliJ IDEA gutter
I mean something like Visual Studio gutter, for example green for saved files and yellow for unsaved files. ( I'm not talking about VCS )

Is there any plugin for this?

[image: example]

I'm talking about "**change tracking**", and visual studio used it

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2018/04/what-the-colors-mean.aspx

Comment: Intellij has auto save enabled by default

Comment: no i mean with disabling auto-save

Comment: I am not sure if such a plugin exist but I am really curious about the use case.

Comment: it is something like Visual studio Gutter, it helps understand what lines are changed or edited without VCS ( with closing the file that history will be disappear )

Comment: Well ... you can use [Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html) for this file (from gutter/editor tab/file context menu etc) and see it all there. But without the actual VCS integration to show it right in the editor ... I'm personally not aware of such plugin or how it can be turned on (would love to know that myself)